# Making an operation to all members in a list of strings in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

I want to make a certain operation to all members in *a list of strings* in Haskell.
For example, I have a list of working time strings (read from an exported Notebook file):

["Working time: 9-17 (8h)",
"Working time: 9-16 (7h)",
"Working time: 10-17 (7h)",
"Working time: 8-17:30 (9.5h)"].

I want to get the amount of working hours in parentheses from each element in this
string list and make a new Double list out of them.

After several hours of searching, I haven't been able to find any example where this
is done. There is an abundance of tricks for Integer lists or functions which take
a long string and make a list of strings from it, but nothing really useful for working
with a list of strings.

Can somebody help?

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: Context: People ask the above usually when the task looks a lot like homework and there is no solid problem, rather more of a "please solve this for me" type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Willem WO:s answer is probably the formally correct one, and also the most adaptable; however, in my case, it was enough to define functions:

```
extractBetween :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a] 
extractBetween a b = drop 1 . takeWhile (/=b) . dropWhile (/=a)

removeLetter :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
removeLetter a = filter (not . isSpace) . takeWhile (`notElem` [a])
```

and the main function to do the work

```
main :: IO()
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  let workHours = ...filter relevant lines...
  let betw = extractBetween '(' ')' <$> workHours
  let hours = removeLetter 'h' <$> betw 
  let totalHours = foldl (+) 0.0 $ read <$> hours
  print "Total working hours this month:"
  print totalHours
```

where  the contents can be read from a text file and *...filter relevant lines...* refers
to filtering the lines with "Working hours: (x h)" from the contents.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is likely working with a regex, we can do this with the `rex` package, so installing it, for example with cabal:

```
cabal install rex
```

and then we can extract this for a single string with a quasi quote:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Text.Regex.PCRE.Rex (rex)

extract :: String -> Double
extract [rex|(?{read -> x}\d+[.]?\d*)h[)]|] = x
extract _ = 0
```

I leave converting the list of strings to a list of `Double` making use of the `extract` function.

Comment: Wow, lots of sugar in there for a beginner to comprehend. Installing packages, imports, quasiquotes, view patterns, regular expressions, equation style function definitions.

Rex is neat looking, but don't take this as the only way or a canonical method.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: well the amount of features is indeed quite large, but rex itself is quite clean in how to use it: even if you don't understand how the `rex` quasi quoter compiles to a view pattern, etc. most people at least have some understanding how to work with it. Just like most people don't understand how a regex itself parses the text, most people can use it.